# find adjacent vertical elements in a grid

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out the thought process behind grabbing adjacent vertical elements in a grid. Say I have a `5x5` grid:

```
 0  1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

I want to find all adjacent horizontal and vertical adjacent elements and place them into an array. The size of the array is given by the possible number of walls between each element (**not** counting the outside) e.g.

```
 1 | 2 | 3
--- --- ---
 4 | 5 | 6
```

A graph of 2x3 has 7 walls so the array would look like

```
1 2
2 3
4 5
5 6 //end of horizontal walls
1 4 //beginning of vertical walls
2 5
3 6
```

now I've figured out how to find all horizontal walls given `rows` and `cols`, where `walls` is the array I will be storing the result in:

```
//find all horizontal walls in grid
//2-d array to store the element between the wall (0 1) (1 2)
for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
  for(int c = 0; c < cols-1; c++){
    int s = r > 0 ? -1*r : 0; //after first row always write over last space
    walls[r*rows+c+s][0] = r*rows+c;
    walls[r*rows+c+s][1] = r*rows+c+1;
  }
}
```

but I'm just getting lost on figuring out how to determine all vertical walls, in a grid of `5x5` for example the vertical walls would be

```
0 5
5 10
10 15
15 20
1 6
6 11
```

etc...

here's what I'm currently trying:

```
for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
  for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++){
    //just print the values at the moment, setting walls properly is easy
    std::cout << r*rows+c*cols << " " << r*rows+c*cols+5 << std::endl;
  }
}
```

only problem is this does not reset after the first column to *1*, instead it continues on like:

```
0 5
5 10
10 15
15 20
20 25 //nope, should be 1 6
```

and suggestions? **pseudo-code is much appreciated I would prefer an explanation over code**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just figured out the solution so I'll post all I did:

the problem I had was rows did not recent back to 1 when the inner for loop left and started again, this was because I was still multiplying `r` by `rows`, this was actually a really simple fix:

`r*rows+c*cols << " " << r*rows+c*cols+5 <<`

becomes

`r+c*cols << " " << r+c*cols+5 <<`

I also was running the inner for loop one too many times so, changing

`c < cols` should become `c < cols-1` and now my output is:

```
0 5
5 10
10 15
15 20
1 6
6 11
11 17
```

etc...